# How to import scss to a LIT(Webcomponent) in Angular

Tags: angular, sass, web-component, lit

I have the following angular code, I am trying to import a scss class, but I do not know how to since on build I got an error

Note there are about 50 more nested .scss calls inside this webcomponent

```
import {
  CSSResultGroup,
  html,
  LitElement,
  PropertyValues,
  TemplateResult,
  unsafeCSS,
} from 'lit';
import cardStyle from './scss/card.scss';
```

But on built, I've got this error

```
./src/web-components/cam-card/scss/card.scss:1:0 - Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:0)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> :host {
|   display: block;
|   position: relative;
```

Do I need to modify anything on tsconfig or something like that?

Comment: First of all, why do you want to import scss in typescript file?

Comment: It is a web component, additionally, there are more scss(50 more) nested inside this web-component

Comment: That's no explanation at all. You don't import SCSS into TS file, it's just not working like that in angular. Please elaborate what you want to accomplish, maybe give us more code.

Comment: Web-components are not part of angular, you can import web-components in angular but they are independent, they need to have their own CSS since they use shadow DOM to implement CSS, Actually that's they key part of web components

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a SCSS stylesheet to a Lit web component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68988650/how-to-add-a-scss-stylesheet-to-a-lit-web-component)

Comment: I have seen something like that before, but I don't know how to do it in Angular, the example is with webpack.config.js

Comment: You can add custom webpack configuration in angular with `@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser` builder. [First tutorial from the internet](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/angular-custom-webpack-config)

Comment: I tried didn't work

Comment: I too am a bit confused about the use case here... I work daily developing enterprise applications via web components and  there are zero examples of our consuming domains needing to import style sheets from the web components themselves. In our Angular domains we just install the npm package/webcomponent, import the self registration file to register the selector, and use that selector in markup (all styling comes along for the ride). Shadow roots are encapsulated and not meant to be pierced... you cannot style them from outside unless the developer specifically writes attributes to do so.

Comment: Yeah, I can put them inside, but here is about putting the CSS in a separate CSS file, not inside the typescript code.